# Securing passwords in production environment

Tags: java, linux, security

We have a Java web application running on JBoss and Linux.  Production environment database connection parameters come from a configuration file that only exists on the production environment app servers.   That config file is only readable by the user ID that also runs the application, (let's call that user appuser) and the only people who can log into production environment servers and sudo to appuser are members of our Operations team.  The production environment itself is firewalled off from all other environments.

We would like to make this more secure.   Specifically we would like to prevent the operations team from reading the database connection password and other keys that are currently in the configuration file.

Another factor to keep in mind is that the operations team is responsible for building and deploying the application.

What are our options?  The solution needs to support manually restarting the application as well as automatically starting the application if the OS reboots.

**Update**

The solution I am investigating now (tip to Adamski for his suggestion, which roughly translates into step 1):

1. Write a wrapper executable that is `setuid` to a user that starts/stops the applications and owns the configuration files and everything in the JBoss directory tree.
2. Use `jarsigner` to sign the WAR after it is built.   The building of the WAR will be done by development.   The `setuid` wrapper will verify the signature, validating that the WAR has not been tampered with.
3. Change the deployment process to only deploy the signed WAR.   The `setuid` wrapper can also move the WAR into place in the JBoss deploy directory.

Comment: Note:  Any signing only makes sense if you use a real certificate and not a selfsigned one.  Additionally the JVM can still be tampered with.

Comment: Right, the JDK install would need to be locked down as well, especially the `cacerts` dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create a second user for the Operations team to sudo to, which only has a subset of file permissions compared with your application's user ID?

No code changes necessary; nice and simple.

Comment: How do they start the application?   Make the startup script setuid?

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way.

Comment: I can't make the script itself setuid (I forgot about this restriction) but I can write a wrapper executable which runs the script, and make the wrapper setuid.

Comment: It's not totally airtight because ops could just deploy their own WAR file and voila, they have access to the config file.

Comment: That begs the question: Why do your Ops team have access to the deploy area?

Comment: They are the ones deploying the app.   They have a script that checks it out of source control, builds it and deploys it.

Comment: Potentially we can tighten up the deployment process, using jarsigner to sign the WAR file.

Comment: How about separating out the database password into a different file from the rest of the config and reading that at runtime when required?  It could simply be an additional .properties file that you read in.

Comment: Ideally no one logging on the system should have access to passwords. Try to make it so using a key-store and/or ssh public/private key pair that no-one logging on that system actually needs to manually enter a password. For Oracle DB's, you could consider Oracle Wallet, that way once authenticated to the system (linux), you are automatically authenticated as the same user on the oracle platform.

Answer (score 3):

You might find it interesting to see how the Jetty folks have approached this problem:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Secure_Passwords

This at least ensures that you cannot just read the password directly but need to some serious effort to get a humanly readable version.

If the Jetty license is compatible with what you want to do, you can just lift their code.

Comment: You would need access to the Jetty decrypt code and the encryption key, both of which would be in source control.  Hmm..

Comment: Let us know what you find. Remember that if a computer Can use it, it Can be decoded.

Comment: Updated question with proposed approach.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use Unix permissions to control who can read these files. However, sensitive data like passwords should never be stored in plain. There are a few alternatives. They require some effort but, that's an approach followed by most commercial products.

Store the passwords encrypted on file system. You can use either Java cryptography or [XML encryption](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/) to do so.

OR

Store sensitive information such as passwords in a database along with other configuration details and encrypt it using database tools. You will still need to store database password somewhere on the file system. Oracle provides a wallet to store the password. There are some third party wallets as well that can do this, if your database vendor does not provide one.