# How to use Typesafe's Config in Scala with encrypted passwords

Tags: scala, configuration, playframework, config, akka

I would like to use [Typesafe's Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) in my project but I don't want any passwords in clear text in any file on the file system of any integration or production server.  Also, I do not want to use [environment variables to store clear text passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461484/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-as-environment-variables-rather-than-as-plain-t).

Ideally, I would like a solution similar to the [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) [EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://heuristicexception.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/secure-your-spring-application-configuration-with-jasypt/) available for Spring that would allow me to designate some property values as being encrypted and have the config system automatically decrypt them before handing the value down to the application.  I'd like to use the JCE keystore to store the key and pass it into my app, but I'm also open to other tools that use a database to store keys.

Has anyone managed to get the Typesafe Config project to work this way?

Update:  sourcedelica was completely correct to criticize the solution that relied on passing the key as an environment variable.  I changed my question to request a solution that uses a more secure way of handling keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try pimping the typesafe `Config` class like so:

```
object ConfigPimping{
  implicit class RichConfig(conf:Config){
    def getPasswordString(path:String, encryptKey:String):String = {
      val encrypted = conf.getString(path)
      val decrypted = ... //do decripy logic of your choice here
      decrypted
    }
  }  
}

object ConfigTest{
  import ConfigPimping._
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
    val myPass = conf.getPasswordString("myPass", "myDecryptKey")
  }
}
```

Then, as long as the `RichConfig` is always imported and available, you can get access to your custom decrpyt logic for passwords via the `getPasswordString` function.

Comment: I ended up writing a tool very much like this.  I will accept your answer and put more details about what I did in my own answer.

Comment: So, rzeleyea can you include more details? :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are happy to pass the encryption key as an environment variable then instead you could pass all of the sensitive properties as environment variables and not worry about using encryption directly with the Typesafe config library.

For example:

```
my.sensitive = ${FOO_ENV}
```

You said that you do not want to use environment variables to store clear text passwords, but if you are storing your encryption key in an environment variable it is the equivalent.

Alternatively you could use a system property instead of an environment variable.  For example, when starting your app, use `-Dmy.sensitive=xxx`.

If you do end up getting encrypted values into your configuration then you could use a wrapper class to that would do the decryption.  [I use a wrapper class](https://gist.github.com/ericacm/4703252) to add methods like `optString` to Config.  You could add a method like `decryptString`.

For a discussion on securing keys to be used in production see my question: [Securing passwords in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810461/securing-passwords-in-production-environment).

Comment: I upvoted your response because it is a valid criticism of my question.  However, it isn't exactly an answer to my question, which asks how to use encrypted keys with Typesafe's config tools.

Comment: Fair enough - added some more commentary

Answer (score 4):

I chose the path that cmbaxter suggested.  I'm putting the example code here because comments don't seem to support code.

I added some special syntax, to the config file, so if I want to put an encrypted password in my config file I do it like this:

```
my-app-config{
  db-username="foo"
  db-password="ENC(9yYqENpuCkkL6gpoVh7a11l1IFgZ0LovX2MBF9jn3+VD0divs8TLRA==)"
}
```

Note the "ENC()" wrapper around the encrypted password.

Then I made a config factory that returns a DycryptingConfig object instead of the typesafe config:

```
import rzrelyea.config.crypto.DecryptingConfig;
import rzrelyea.config.crypto.KeyProvider;

public class ConfigFactory{

public static final Config makeDecryptingConfig(com.typesafe.config.Config config, KeyProvider keyProvider){
    return new DecryptingConfig(config, keyProvider);
}
```

}

And here's the code for the DecryptingConfig:

```
import java.security.Key;    
import static rzrelyea.config.Validators.require;

public class DecryptingConfig extends rzrelyae.config.Config {

    private final com.typesafe.config.Config config;
    private final Decryptor decryptor;

    public DecryptingConfig(com.typesafe.config.Config config, KeyProvider keyProvider){
        super(config);
        require(keyProvider, "You must initialize DecryptingConfig with a non-null keyProvider");
        this.config = config;
        final Key key = keyProvider.getKey();
        require(key, "KeyProvider must provide a non-null key");
        decryptor = new Decryptor(config.getString("crypto-algorithm"), key, config.getString("encoding-charset"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String s) {
        final String raw = config.getString(s);
        if (EncryptedPropertyUtil.isEncryptedValue(raw)){
            return decryptor.decrypt(EncryptedPropertyUtil.getInnerEncryptedValue(raw));
        }
        return raw;
    }
```

Obviously, you'd need to implement your own rzrelyea.config.Config object, your own EncryptedPropertyUtil, your own Decryptor, and your own KeyProvider.  My implementation of rzrelya.config.Config takes a typesafe config object as a constructor parameter and forwards all calls to it.  LOTS of boiler plate code in it!  But I thought it was better to forward calls to an interface rather than to extend com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.  You know, prefer composition to inheritance and code to interfaces, not implementations.  You may choose a different route.

Comment: I am newbie to typesafe... I would like to see sample working code with details . This will help to understand the complete load process

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of telling you something you already know...

- Never store a password -- store and compare against a hash instead
- Use Bcrypt for password hashes -- it's slow which is good for guarding against a brute-force attack
- Use a salt -- to guard against a rainbow table style attack
- Use SSL (https) -- to prevent passwords from being seen in the clear

Here is an example that uses the [Mindrot jBCrypt library](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/):

```
  def PasswordHash( name:String, pwd:String, version:Int = 1 ) : String = {
    if( version == 2 && false )
    {
      // ANY CHANGES SHOULD BE MADE AS A NEW VERSION AND ADDED HERE
      ""
    }
    else
    {
      import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt      // jbcrypt-0.3m.jar

      // Salt will be incorporated in the password hash
      val salt = BCrypt.gensalt(12) // Default is 10, or 2**10 rounds.  More rounds is slower.

      BCrypt.hashpw( (name + pwd), salt )
    }
  }

  def VerifyPassword( name:String, pwd:String, hash:String, version:Int = 1 ) : Boolean = {
    if( version == 1 )
    {
      import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt      // jbcrypt-0.3m.jar

      BCrypt.checkpw( (name + pwd), hash )
    }
    else
      false
  }
```

**> PasswordHash( "johnny", "mypassword" )**
res4: String = $2a$12$dHIlTL14.t37Egf7DqG4qePE446GzzhIUAVuewMfkhfK0xxw3NW6i

**> VerifyPassword( "johnny", "mypassword",           "$2a$12$dHIlTL14.t37Egf7DqG4qePE446GzzhIUAVuewMfkhfK0xxw3NW6i" )**
res5: Boolean = true

**> VerifyPassword( "johnny", "mommiespassword", "$2a$12$dHIlTL14.t37Egf7DqG4qePE446GzzhIUAVuewMfkhfK0xxw3NW6i" )**
res6: Boolean = false

*For what you are trying to do, I presume you would store the "name", "password hash", and "hash version" in your configuration.*

Comment: I guess OP wants to store password for DB connection setup or something like that, not store it for accessing control. In this case, we must know exactly what the password is.

Comment: Brian Hsu is correct.  I need to be able to decrypt the password stored in a config file so that I can authenticate with the database.

Comment: The javax.crypto package will have the encryption/decryption routines.  You may want to check if your database supports a "trusted connection".  It would be a more secure way to connect to the DB and not require storing a password in the configuration.